# how to move label to certain area

Tags: html, css-float, label, text-align

I have a label that is above a GridView. Right now the label is in the center.

```
 <div id="mem" style="text-align:center">
      <label>Member Outturn</label>
 </div>
```

I want the label above the Qty Rcvd column of the GridView. But as you can see from the image, setting the label to center isn't above the correct column.

[image]

So how do I move the label over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using margin-left it is a lot easier to position the label where ever you want

```
<div id="mem" style="margin-left:710px">
   <label>Member Outturn</label>
</div>
```